# Can you open()/write() twice the same file in the same function but with different options (O_Append,O_create) in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement simple and double redirection, if it's double I would like to open the file in mode O_Append and O_Create if it's a simple redirection.
But when the value of f is 2 it doesn't change the output options to O_append.

I've tried doing it with different int names but it didn't work at all.

Here is the problematic function:

```
void DoubleRedirectionIn(char* parsed, char** strredoublein, int f)
{
    int nbread = 0;

    unsigned char buff[4096];
    int input = open(parsed, O_RDONLY);
    
    printf("f vaut %i", f);
    
    int output;
    if (f != 2) {
        output = open(strredoublein[0], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00777);
    }
    else {
        output = open(strredoublein[0], O_RDWR| O_APPEND , 00777);
    }
    while ((nbread = read(input, buff, 3000)) > 0) {
        write(output, buff, nbread);
        printf("ca a copié le fichier");
    }
    close(input);
    close(output);
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. As far as I can see, everything is opened once.

Comment: Yes but the second open (in else, when f==2 ) isn't working , I've put printf() in the else to be sure that it passes in it (and it does goes inside the else) . And I've also switched the different mode in open and it seems it only takes the first modes of  open it encounters .

Comment: None of this makes any sense to me. Please post a [mcve] (just add a `main` function that calls `DoubleRedirectionIn` directly, and also explain what files you expect to be in the current working directory).

Comment: Actually I reformated the code to make it simpler and post it here and while doing that I've found out why it wasn't working ( I was passing a char** as an argument of open instead of a char*).Thanks for your remarks.